# mysql rows where count(x) > 1 and count(y) > 0

Tags: mysql

I have a sales table containing invoice number, product code, product category, qty, etc.

Using this table how would you go about finding invoices that contain at least one product from say category A AND 1 product from category B ?

Comment: You really need to supply more details such as table structure and sample data.

Comment: I don't quite see the table relations, but how about "...WHERE EXISTS(...category = 'A') AND EXISTS(...category = 'B')..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's what I believe is what you'll want. Happy to see any simpler suggestions if anyone has them:

```
Select tableA.invoiceNumber
from 
(select * from myTable
where productCategory = 'A') tableA
inner join
(select * from myTable
 where productCategory = 'B') tableB
 on tableA.invoiceNumber = tableB.invoiceNumber
```

Here's a SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03ddd/3

It's basically joining your query onto itself where there's a condition for each table on category.

Comment: the product category field would contain values such as 'category A' or 'category B' so I'm looking for invoiceNumber that contain at least one row containing 'category A' in product category field AND at least one row containing 'category B' in product category field .. does that help ?

Comment: Ah, that's a bit different, give me a minute and I'll edit my answer. Is there a primary key on the table?

Comment: The above query should work, check the SQL fiddle in case it helps clarify what's being brought back.

Comment: hmmm, this should work it seems but I'm getting error Unknown column 'sales.invoiceNumber' in 'field list'

Comment: That's not a column in my SQL fiddle, or in my query.

Comment: Great! If you're curious, it's basically creating two tables, one with only category A, the other with only category b. As it inner joins on the invoice, it returns only rows where there's an invoice in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    select * from mytable
inner join(
select invoiceNumber
from mytable
where mytable.productcategory = 'A'
) as a using (invoiceNumber)
inner join(
select invoiceNumber
from mytable
where mytable.productcategory = 'B') as b
using (invoiceNumber)
group by invoicenumber
```

Comment: I think this will return any invoices with category A or B.

Comment: @Tim3880 Just updated my answer. It;s return invoice that contain at least 1 category A and 1 category B.

Comment: Thanks and it looks good to me. I just look around and learn.

Comment: thanks this works, although took over a minute to run !